# Viewing data returned from Ajax.BeginForm

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, client-side

I have a small segment of code which uses Ajax to make a server-side call. The method it calls (SaveNewSoftware) returns true if an entered name doesn't exist, and false if the name is already present. I have defined a method which can be used to handle the returned data from the server; my issue is that I do not know how I can view the returned data from the Ajax call.

Here is my Ajax call:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("SaveNewSoftware", "Software", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "environmentcontent", HttpMethod = "Post", OnSuccess = "handleData()" },
```

And here is the method which handles the returned data:

```
<script>
    function handleData(data) {
        if(data === 'true')
        {
            CloseModal('#myModalWindowstack1');
            AddAlert('#alertarea', 'New Software Has Been Added!');
        }
        else
        {
            CloseModal('#myModalWindowstack1');
            AddAlert('#alertarea', 'Software with that name already exists');
        }
    }
</script>
```

How can I pass the returned data from the Ajax call to my handleData method?

Comment: simply pass data coming from controller action as `...OnSuccess = "handleData(data)"`

Comment: @Novastorm what is your return type for the method you have created

Comment: It is a boolean being returned

Comment: @kartikeya How can I pass that data back? Simply calling "handleData(data)" doesn't appear to pass anything to the handleData method when I checked it

Comment: this should work..just check whether your action result is returning bool or something else.

Comment: @Novastorm remove your braces () in handledata on onsuccess attribute in ajax.beginform

Comment: @kartikeya Debugging server-side reveals that a boolean is being returned, however I'm unsure if this gets 'transformed' into something else when it hits the Ajax part. I popped a console.log(data) inside both parts of the if statement and nothing is being output into the web console if that helps gives any clues to what might be happening. The method is definitely being hit though, as the AddAlert() method is being called

Comment: post your actionresult code as well.

Comment: Forgive me for what is probably a rather silly question, but where would I find my action result? This is my first time working my way around Ajax.BeginForm :)

Answer (score 0):

You need not have to call () the method when you assign to `OnSuccess` method. Just `OnSuccess= handleData` is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Just pass the same parameter to the function call as well

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("SaveNewSoftware", "Software", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "environmentcontent", HttpMethod = "Post", OnSuccess = "handleData(data)" }
```

if this doesn't work try adding single quotes around the data.

```
"handleData('"+data+"')"
```

Hope it helps.